# How to Draw a Ray Along a Sprite in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to cast a ray along a sprite in Unity. I have Created an empty GameObject and made it as Parent to different Textures of Head, Hand, Chest etc of a Character to easily Animate it, Now for Melee Combat I would like to Cast a Ray along the Hand Texture while it Animates the Attack but I am Unable to get the Centre of the Hand Texture in the Scene.
I am trying to Access the Sprite by the following Code

```
Sprite Hand = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren <Transform> () [4].GetComponentsInChildren <Transform> () [0].gameObject.GetComponent <SpriteRenderer> ().sprite;
```

This Code is Working for accessing the Hand Transform I verified by Drawing a Ray from the transforms centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to find it at run time, just link it together in the prefab/gameobject. It's pretty simple to just expose it in the inspector then drag the sprite to the exposed variable. You could do a sprite or a transform, in the example below I used a transform, but if you need to get more data from it then go on ahead and use a sprite.

```
public Transform Head;
public Transform Hand;
public Transform Chest;
```

Then you can get the position with Head.position

If you are looking to check for collisions consider placing a collider at each location, then you can toggle them on/off when you want (so the hand collider is disabled unless if the character is punching, then you turn it on for the duration (or part of it) of the punch.) Then you can have a component on just that collider for doing damage or finding a wall or whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Enabling the collider works fine but how do I identify Collision on the public Transform Hand @Formic

Comment: You wouldn't. Instead have a component on the transform with the collider. This helps keep the behaviors isolated, which is great. This component would manage the desired behavior. If you really want to have the code in the class that is enabling/disabling the colliders, then just build a component that broadcasts the message back to its owner. So expose a gameobject in the component that is the owner, then you can use send message to raise the event and pass data to the owner (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html)

Comment: What if I want to Know the position of the Textute during Runtime @Formic